# Is void** an acceptable type in ANSI-C?

Tags: c, void

I have seen a function whose prototype is:

```
int myfunc(void** ppt)
```

This function is called in a C file as 
    a = myfunc(mystruct **var1);

where mystruct is typedef for one of structure we have.

This works without any compilation errors in MSVC6.0, But when I compile it with some other C compiler, it gives an error at the place where this function is called with error message:

**Argument of type mystruct ** is incompatible with parameter of type void ****

The argument of myfunc() is kept as void** because it seems to be a generic malloc kind of function to be called with various structure variable types for memory allocation

1. Is there any type such as void ** allowed in C standard/any C compilers?
2. How do I fix this? [I tried casting the function call argument to `mystruct**`, but it didn't work]

-AD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`void**` *is* valid but, based on your error message, you probably have to explicitly cast the argument as follows:

```
mystruct **var1;
x = myfunc ((void**) var1);
```

That's because the `myfunc` function is expecting the `void**` type. While `void*` can be implicitly cast to any other pointer, that is not so for the double pointer - you need to explicitly cast it.

Comment: This invokes undefined behavior (modifying an object through a pointer to the wrong type). The API is just broken; any allocation-type function that allocates generic memory (`void *`) needs to return the pointer rather than taking a double-pointer argument. Fortunately such broken APIs can just be wrapped to fix them...

Comment: Modifying it via a different pointer may well be undefined but that's not being done here. I'm casting to get rid of the error and all pointers can be cast to and from void pointers in a defined manner. To avoid UB, you will have to cast it back to the correct type before trying to dereference it - this is a given since you cannot dereference a `void*` type anyway - the compiler doesn't know the underlying type. The OP made it clear this use of a void pointer was so that different pointer types could be sent in, so it seems acceptable here and there's only UB if it's not cast back correctly.

Comment: The called function then modifies (or at least accesses) the object via the wrong type. It reads or writes it as `void *` when the actual type is `mystruct *` and these types are not compatible. `void **` is not like `void *`; it's not a universal double pointer.

Comment: Thanks for fixing; I have deleted my comment and cancelled the downvote.

Answer (score 22):

The [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/) addresses this issue in detail in [Question 4.9](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/genericpp.html). In short, they say **it's not strictly portable** to cast an arbitrary pointer-to-pointer to a `void **`; they go on to explain that "code like this may work and is sometimes recommended, but it relies on all pointer types having the same internal representation (which is common, but not universal)." They go on to explain that "any `void **` value you play with must be the address of an actual `void *` value somewhere; casts like `(void **)&dp`, though they may shut the compiler up, are nonportable (and may not even do what you want)."

So, you can safely/portably achieve the desired behavior with code like:

```
some_type *var1 = foo();
void *tmp_void_ptr = (void *)var1;
myfunc(&tmp_void_ptr);
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a reason the compiler cannot automatically cast from `mystruct**` to `void**`.

Consider the following code:

```
void stupid(struct mystruct **a, struct myotherstruct **b)
{
    void **x = (void **)a;
    *x = *b;
}
```

The compiler will not complain about the implicit cast from `myotherstruct*` to `void*` in the `*x = *b` line, even though that line is trying to put a pointer to a `myotherstruct` in a place where only pointers to `mystruct` should be put.

The mistake is in fact in the previous line, which is converting "a pointer to a place where pointers to `mystruct` can be put" to "a pointer to a place where pointers to *anything* can be put". *This* is the reason there is no implicit cast. Of course, when you use a explicit cast, the compiler assumes you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

This question is slightly confusing. But yes, `void **` is certainly legal and valid C, and means "pointer to pointer to `void`" as expected.

I'm not sure about your example of a call, the arguments ("mystruct **var1") don't make sense. If `var1` is of type `mystruct **`, the call should just read `a = func(var1);`, this might be a typo.

Casting should work, but you need to cast to `void **`, since that is what the function expects.

Answer (score 0):

As dirty as it may look like: sometimes you can't solve a problem without using void **.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `void **` is perfectly acceptable and quite useful in certain circumstances. Also consider that given the declaration `void **foo` and `void *bar`, the compiler will know the size of the object pointed to by foo (it points to a pointer, and all pointers are the same size except on a few ancient platforms you needn't worry about), but it will not know the size of the object pointed to by bar (it could point to an object of any size). You can therefore safely perform pointer arithmetic on `void **` pointers but **not** on `void *` pointers. You must cast them to something else first, like a `char *`. GCC will allow you to pretend that `void *` and `char *` are equivalent, each pointing to an object a single byte in size, but this is nonstandard and nonportable.