# incompatible pointer type in C

Tags: c

so I'm trying to pass a type `double *` to a function that accepts `void **` as one of the parameters. This is the warning that I am getting.

```
incompatible pointer type passing 'double **' to parameter of type 'void **'
```

Here is a snippet of my code.

```
int main( void )
{
    //  Local Declaration
    double *target;

   //   Statement
   success = dequeue(queueIn, &target);
}
```

Here's the prototype declaration of the function.

```
int    dequeue     ( QUEUE *queue, void **dataOutPtr );
```

I thought that if I passed target as a two level pointer that it would work, but I guess I'm wrong. Can someone please explain to me how come i'm getting this warning?

Comment: @GreenMatt The type signature for dequeue expecta pointer to a pointer. Look again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is void\*\* an acceptable type in ANSI-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246280/is-void-an-acceptable-type-in-ansi-c)

Comment: http://ideone.com/VGvqFe

Comment: This is very likely a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246280/is-void-an-acceptable-type-in-ansi-c

Comment: @Nathan Refer to the above links(by me and Cody Gray).You'll find good answers to this question.

Comment: So, you've solved the casting issue. The bigger issue is likely what form of data the `dequeue` function is expecting. I bet it's not a pointer to an uninitialised pointer to double.

Answer (score 7):

Even though all other pointer types can be converted to and from `void *` without loss of information, the same is not true of `void **` and other pointer-to-pointer types; if you dereference a `void **` pointer, it needs to be pointing at a genuine `void *` object<sup>1</sup>.

In this case, presuming that `dequeue()` is returning a single pointer value by storing it through the provided pointer, to be formally correct you would need to do:

```
int main( void )
{
    void *p;
    double *target;

    success = dequeue(queueIn, &p);
    target = p;
```

When you write it like this, the conversion from `void *` to `double *` is explicit, which allows the compiler to do any magic that's necessary (even though in the overwhelmingly common case, there's no magic at all).

---

<sup>1. ...or a `char *`, `unsigned char *` or `signed char *` object, because there's a special rule for those.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

In your prototype declaration , you said second argument as `void**` ,so you have to type cast `double**` to `void**`.
Instead of this line `success = dequeue(queueIn, &target);`.

Call like this `success = dequeue(queueIn,(void**) &target);`

Comment: Why is the cast necessary? Aren't all pointers interpret-able as void pointers?

Comment: @valek That's true for `void*`, but not for the double-pointer `void**`. Details are [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246280/is-void-an-acceptable-type-in-ansi-c).

Comment: okay, yeah, type casting did take the warning off, but now my data for target isn't being recognize. One problem solve, but another one raises haha.

Comment: @Nathan It's obvious that it now doesn't recognize the data as you have stripped off its identity by casting it to void**.

Comment: This can be a bit dangerous sometimes. We once had 2 userdefined free-methods. One would take `void*` as argument and just free the memory, the other would take `void**` as argument and free as well as reset the pointer. If you call it without a cast it always uses the `void*`-variant, even if you passed the reference of a pointer which effectively resulted in freeing UB. I would avoid `void**` altogether.

Comment: "*so you have to type cast `doublee**` to `void**`*": [-1](http://www.c-faq.com/ptrs/genericpp.html).

Answer (score -1):

```
int main( void )
{
    //  Local Declaration
    double *target;

   //   Statement
   success = dequeue(queueIn, (void**)&target);
}
```

Use it like this.

Comment: What does this change? Why does he need to make this change?

Comment: Assuming the queue is a list of "pointers to doubles", this is likely correct. Hard to say without knowing more about the library of code.