# Allocating through a pointer to a pointer parameter

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, malloc, void-pointers

I have this macro:

```
/*
 * int  callocs(type **ptr, size_t nmemb);
 *
 * Safe & simple wrapper for `calloc()`.
 *
 * PARAMETERS:
 * ptr:     Memory will be allocated, and a pointer to it will be stored
 *          in *ptr.
 * nmemb:   Number of elements in the array.
 *
 * RETURN:
 *  0:          OK.
 *  != 0:       Failed.
 *
 * FEATURES:
 * - Safely computes the element size (second argument to `calloc()`).
 * - Returns non-zero on error.
 * - Doesn't cast.
 * - The pointer stored in `*ptr` is always a valid pointer or NULL.
 *
 * EXAMPLE:
 *      #define ALX_NO_PREFIX
 *      #include <libalx/base/stdlib/alloc/callocs.h>
 *
 *              int *arr;
 *
 *              if (callocs(&arr, 7))       // int arr[7];
 *                      goto err;
 *
 *              // `arr` has been succesfully allocated here
 *              free(arr);
 *      err:
 *              // No memory leaks
 */
#define callocs(ptr, nmemb) (                                           \
{                                                                       \
        __auto_type     ptr_    = (ptr);                                \
                                                                        \
        *ptr_   = calloc(nmemb, sizeof(**ptr_));                        \
                                                                        \
        !(*ptr_);                                                       \
}                                                                       \
)
```

and I would like it to be a function to improve safety.  This would be the first idea:

```
#define callocs(ptr, nmemb) (                                           \
{                                                                       \
        __auto_type     ptr_    = (ptr);                                \
                                                                        \
        callocs__(ptr_, nmemb, sizeof(**ptr_));                         \
}                                                                       \
)


int     callocs__(void **ptr, ptrdiff_t nmemb, size_t size)
{

        if (nmemb < 0)
                goto ovf;

        *ptr    = calloc(nmemb, size);

        return  !*ptr;
ovf:
        errno   = ENOMEM;
        *ptr    = NULL;
        return  ENOMEM;
}
```

But then the compiler complains with:

```
error: passing argument 1 of callocs__ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
note: in expansion of macro callocs
note: expected void ** but argument is of type struct My_Struct **
```

Is a simple explicit cast to `(void **)` safe?:

```
#define callocs(ptr, nmemb) (                                           \
{                                                                       \
        __auto_type     ptr_    = (ptr);                                \
                                                                        \
        callocs__((void **)ptr_, nmemb, sizeof(**ptr_));                \
}                                                                       \
)
```

By safe I mean both from the Standard point of view (which I guess is not) and from implementations point of view (in this specific case, GNU C) (which I'm not sure).

And if not, would an intermediate pointer of type `void *` be enough?:

```
#define callocs(ptr, nmemb) (                                           \
{                                                                       \
        __auto_type     ptr_    = (ptr);                                \
        void            *vp_;                                           \
        int             ret_;                                           \
                                                                        \
        ret_    = callocs__(&vp_, nmemb, sizeof(**ptr_))                \
        *ptr_   = vp_;                                                  \
        ret_;                                                           \
}                                                                       \
)
```

Is there any other solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is void\*\* an acceptable type in ANSI-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246280/is-void-an-acceptable-type-in-ansi-c)

Comment: "I have this macro: ... `callocs`,  and I would like it to be a function to improve safety" -->   By "it", sounds like you want `callocs` to be a function, yet in the first idea, `callocs` remains a macro. Please clarify.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I meant having all the code that can be in a function be moved into a function, and the remaining (`sizeof(**ptr_)`, which can't go into a function) go into a less dangerous macro.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I'm not sure.  It says it's not portable, which I suspected.  But on POSIX all pointers have the same representation, which would make it (the explicit cast) portable (on POSIX at least) if that were the only problem.  But still I don't know if on some weird GCC optimizations that would bite me.  There is also the problem that malloc (and calloc) are a bit special and I don't know if the compiler will do the right thing through a `void **`.

Comment: CacahueteFrito "But on POSIX all pointers have the same representation" are you sure object pointers and function pointer are specified by POSIX to have the same representation?  IAC, I think it is only object pointers of concern for this post.

Comment: The code is somewhat dubious. `calloc` of 0 elements is allowed to return a null pointer, but it isn't a failure as such.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala C17 changed that a bit.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Although it may or may not be an error for the standard, I think for a simple & safe usage of this macro/function, I should return != 0, so that if return == 0 the pointer can be dereferenced and else it can't.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica About POSIX: I'm not completely sure, but here's all I could get: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html

Comment: You can't reference a pointer that was callocated with 0 elements even if non-null

Comment: @cacahuete: that is about convertability of  *values* not representation

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Am I missing something?  `if (!size || !nmemb)` calloc will return `NULL`, and therefore I will store `NULL` in the passed pointer and return a non-zero error code, so that the user doesn't try to further use the pointer.

Comment: On the contrary, the documentation explicitly says that only cast to and from void * is allowed, not to any other pointer type

Comment: *"If either nelem or elsize is 0, then either **a null pointer or a unique pointer value that can be successfully passed to free() shall be returned.**"*

Comment: @AnttiHaapala OK, so to be safer I should prevent calling `calloc(0, whatever)` or `calloc(whatever, 0)` and manage those error cases myself instead.  Thanks!

Comment: CacahueteFrito On the side issue of allocating zero memory, code could use `if (size == 0 || count = 0) ptr = malloc(1);` or `if (size == 0 || count = 0) ptr = NULL;` and avoid implementation defined behavior.  The first follows your model more.  the 2nd is more space conservative.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica  I did the second one, mainly because someone could write `callocs(&ptr, 0)` (for some obscure reasons) and expect not having to free the pointer.  Also it is more logic that if my function returns a non-zero error code, meaning that something went wrong, I can't expect that the user will still free the pointer.  Safer to return NULL and avoid leaks at all.  I chose to differentiate error codes into positive (zero size allocation) and negative (allocation failure) to better inform the user.  BTW, great answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is a simple explicit cast to (void **) safe?:
>   And if not, would an intermediate pointer of type void * be enough?:

The `(void **)` approach is reasonable, yet relies on `some_other_type **` being compatible with `void **`.  It falls under:

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined. Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. C17dr § 6.3.2.2 7

So trouble in a rare case of a pointer to one type has a different alignment requirement than a pointer to a `void *`.  I doubt such an implementation exists.  To be clear, this is a difference of alignment requirement of pointer types, not the objects they point to.

---

> Is there any other solution?

To avoid "passing argument 1 of callocs__ from incompatible pointer type" and to maintain type correctness, consider making the helper function `callocs__()` as

```
void *callocs__(ptrdiff_t nmemb, size_t size, int *error);
// ^------------return pointer to allocated data
```

Then

```
#define callocs(ptr, nmemb) (                             \
{                                                         \
        __auto_type     ptr_    = (ptr);                  \
        int error;                                        \
        *ptr = callocs__(nmemb, sizeof(**ptr_), &error);  \
        error;                                            \
}                                                         \
)
```

---

Note: I applaud the the overall objective of making a function to handle the  subtle [vagaries](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vagary) of `*alloc()`.